# Lithium-ion batteries lose capacity over their lifetime, but what about 100% voltage?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

Over the lifetime of a Lithium-ion battery (charge cycles), does the maximum voltage that the battery can be charged to decrease, or does it remain the same, and only the capacitance decreases (internal resistance increases)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, its voltages remain the same, it's just that they last shorter, in other words they change faster under the same load or charge current due to lower capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Li-ion cells don't "lose voltage", as you say. Although a few characteristics of Li-ion cells change over time (most notably a reduction is capacity and an in crease in DC resistance), their Open Circuit Voltage vs SoC doesn't change noticeably over time *.

On the different matter of maximum charge voltage, *you* are in charge of it, not the cell. If  *you* wish to charge a Li-ion cell at a different voltage as it ages, you are free to do so. The question then becomes: should you? And should you increase it or decrease it?

Indeed, in sophisticated applications, the top charge voltage is changed as the cell ages:

- When the cell is new, the application uses a narrower range of its SoC, such as 20 % to 80 %, for the sake of long lifetime (i.e., a lower top voltage)
- As the cell ages, the application slowly increases that range to achieve the same effective capacity as a new cell  (i.e., an increased top voltage)
- Once the application reaches 0 to 100 % SoC, the entire capacity of the cell is used, and it starts degrading faster  (i.e., the maximum top voltage)
- Beyond that, the user starts noticing a reduced performance

---

(*) Yes, it does change slightly, which is something that a scientist in a laboratory can detect, but you and I can't.

Comment: Thanks. This is for an electric unicycle battery pack with 20 pairs of of LG MJ1 cells in series for a total of "84 volts". Reported max charge voltage is 83.6 volts, which hasn't changed in 18 months of usage, causing me to wonder if circuitry in the pack (like passive balancing) was the reason that the maxed charged voltage hasn't changed.  Usage is light, I only do 100% charge once every 1 to 2 months, most of the time stored at 3.8 volts per cell, and mostly short rides that use 30% of charge (around 15% charge before a ride, 15% charge after a ride).

Answer (score 0):

The state of charge versus battery voltage is generally linear between 10% and 90% charge for most of the consumer-type Li-ion batteries. Also, as the battery ages, the slope of the curve decreases as well i.e. reaching to 50% from 100% gets shorter time.

So the max charge voltage decreases over time as well.

Comment: _the slope of the curve decreases as well_ Not exactly correct: the OCV vs SoC remains the same, regardless of capacity. _ i.e. reaching to 50% from 100% gets shorter time_ Correct.

Comment: @DavideAndrea `the OCV vs SoC remains the same, regardless of capacity.` If you have any source or experiment report I'd like to see. For the first couple of hundred cycles the slope may not change but after that the slope will change noticeably.

Comment: Please let me turn it around and ask you to provide evidence that the slope of the  the OCV vs SoC changes over time. I think you must be thinking of something different: the slope over **time** not over SoC. Yes, the slope of the **terminal voltage** (not the OCV) over **time** during charge (not the SoC, regardless of charging or discharging) does get steeper because the charging time for a lower capacity cell is less. But the shape for the OCV vs SoC curve stays the same, no matter how much the cell capacity decreases.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Alright, the confusion comes from the difference between the charge amounts (Q) of aged and fresh batteries, and from the definition of "fully charged". If we take the SOC as 100% when the OCV hits 4.2V (like smartphones do) then yes, the slope won't change because SOC is relative. I must be confusing the total charge amount *(or in other words, capacity)* with SOC here because the total Q (capacity) gets lower as the battery ages. From the total Q point of view the curves will have different slopes like [here](https://imgur.com/a/5q4DlLd). My paint skills may not be that good.

Comment: I spoke to a battery professional for military applications and their experiments are in line with what I drew. And also, he told me that SOC is meaningless without SOH (state of health) so 100% is never 100%. So the vertical shift I have shown is SOH indication which makes 100% SOC meaningful for only 0th cycle.